Timer Elapsed Error
He creado un timer para que cada 1 segundos haya una cuenta regresiva en una label, que indica cuanto tiempo se tarda en lanzar una foto. Con el timer por la pestaña de Diseño me funciona bien, pero cuando he cambiado la webcam a una mejor no me funciona.
Por lo tanto he cambiado a hacer el timer por código.
Timer t = new Timer(1000);

        private void kryptonButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // startCountDown();
            bytePlc("1");
            label1.Visible = true;
            seconds = 5;
            
            t.Elapsed += EventoElapsed;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void EventoElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (seconds == 0)
            {
                label1.Visible = false;


            }
            
            label1.Text = seconds--.ToString();
            if (seconds < -1)
            {
                t.Stop();
                lanzarFoto();

            }
        }

EL problema es que me salta en la linea label1.Text = seconds--.ToString(); el error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'label1' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.'


Que error es el CS0120?? en serio nos vas a hacer ir a buscarlo??? lo otro que escribiste, obviametne no va a andar nunca.. abriste un nuevo form, una nueva clase, un nuevo objeto.. no el que ves en pantalla... los form son objetos como cualquier otra.. un new, es uno nuevo...

Agregar todo el código y señalar en que línea salta el error

He conseguido solucionarlo añadiendo Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False  . No se si es la mejor solución...

no.. no solo no es la mejor solucion.. es muy mala... Lo que tenes que hacer es decirle al thread principal que actualice el label como corresponde... busca sobre Invoke para eso...

justo he visto que no era buena solución...no me actualizaba bien la UI. He probado tambien con Invoke con lo siguiente: this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>label1.Text = seconds--.ToString())); pero me da fallo en otra función, creo que viene porque el timer crea un subproceso de trabajo y tengo un picture box el cual me pone que el objeto ya esta siendo usado.

Es posible para ese subproceso justo o antes de cuando hago el t.Stop();

se hace como pusiste arriba.. si te da problemas en otro lado, vamos a necesitar un ejemplo completo de tus procesos y como replicarlo... asi como esta, imposible saber que pasa...
